# Show pause menu when app enters background

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

In my app I have a `showPauseMenu` method that pause the director and shows my pause menu. What I would like is to have this method automatically called when the app enters the background (when the person receives a phone call, hits the home button, etc.). I believe I'm going to have to use a class method or something like that. Any ideas?

Update: I now have the method successfully being called upon the app re-entering the foreground. The director gets paused but my menu to unease never shows up. My menu is a CCLayer that while the app is in the foreground is off-screen. So in the `pauseGameLayer` I simply set the `pauseMenuLayer.position = ccp(0,0);` and pause the director. Like I said the director gets paused but the layer doesn't move to the new position.

Comment: you don't want to do this when the app enters background, but when it comes back and enters foreground.

Comment: Why do I want to do it then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To best solve my problem of having a pause menu pop up on its own when the app enters the background, this is what I did. I first set up a variable (`isPlaying`) in my singleton class.  If the app was about to enter the background (I used `applicationWillResignActive` in the AppDelegate) `isPlaying` was set to `TRUE`. In my update function within the game would check to see if `isPlaying` was set to `TRUE` and as soon as it was it would launch the the function to display the pause menu. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You want to implement the message `applicationWillResignActive` in your app delegate.

See:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillResignActive:

and

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html

Comment: Is there a difference between putting it in `applicationWillResignActive` and in `applicationDidEnterBackground`?

Comment: I added it there but the actual method does not seem to be being called.

Comment: it should be, you might want to update your question with what you tried. do note that `applicationWillResignActive:` takes an argument.